# BLOB to String[][]

Tags: android, blob, ksoap2

Is there a way to directly convert a "BLOB"-array into a String[][]-array (on Android?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I don't know very much about android, but it's written in Java, yes? So then what you need to do is convert the individual elements of the BLOB array.

Comment: Yes, it's written in Java. Unfortunately I don't really know how to convert the individual elements of the blob array.

Comment: Is there a method for each element to convert it to a string array?

Comment: If an answer has helped you, please choose it as the best answer. Otherwise answer the question with the solution you found and select that as the best answer.

Comment: I would have, but unfortunately none of the answers really helped me. I solved the issue I had a different way withouth coding blob to String[][].

Comment: Then post your solution and mark that as best answer, so that people with the same question in the future can see your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution doesn't require codingBLOBs to String[][]-arrays anymore, now I am (de-)coding SoapEnvelopes to byte-arrays and vice versa using a method described here: http://androiddevblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/serializing-and-parceling-ksoap2.html

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, blobs return bytes. So you want to build a byte array and then build the string from that. [This is an example.](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-convert-a-jdbc-blob-to-a-string)

Hope it gives you a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Converting blob array to string array:

```
BLOB[] blobs = getBlobs(); //fetch it somehow
String[] strings = new String[blobs.length];
for(int i = 0; i < blobs.length; i++)
    strings[i] = new String(blobs[i].getBytes(0, blobs[i].length());
return strings;
```

Converting blob array to string matrix:

```
BLOB[] blobs = getBlobs(); //fetch it somehow
String[][] strings = new String[blobs.length][];
for(int i = 0; i < blobs.length; i++)
    strings[i] = blobToStringArray(blobs[i]);
return strings;
```

Comment: I thought as much, but what about converting a BLOB to a String[][]-array? How do I know which of the bytes belong to which of the array?

Comment: How are you planning on converting it? You would need to represent a BLOB as an array of strings. I'll post an example above.

Comment: Thank you for your example, unfortunately "getBlobs" only returns a byte[]-array, not a blob array as the name would suggest. Certain operations are not available with the byte-array

Comment: You'll need to find some way to convert a BLOB to a string array. Could you provide some more context on what exactly you're doing?